# Reference static library project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, static-libraries

**TL;DR: How do I make a project depends on another static library project in visual studio**

I'm trying to make a small C++ project which uses this library: http://finitetransform.sourceforge.net/

The library contains of two projects. NTTW and FRTW where FRTW depends on NTTW. My project should depend on FRTW.
Both NTTW and FRTW and relatively small and simple libraries without any external dependencies (apart form the c standard libraries)

Now I'm new to C++ development in Visual studio, but I've been googling for days which any luck on how to set this up.

*This is what I want:* I want a Solution in visual studio where I can build NTTW, FRTW and them my own Playground app where I can play with the libraries. I want to build both the libraries from source since I might want to edit them.

*This is what I have:* I've created a solution with in Visual Studio with the structure I want. I've created my own project (a c++ console application) and a project for NTTW and one for FRTW - both are created a "static library".

Since the libraries are written in C I have disabled precompiled headers in order to make them build.
Then I added NTTW as a dependency for FRTW and FRTW as a dependency for my playground project.

What works: NTTW build just fine. However, FRTW does not because it can not link to NTTW. When I try to build it I get these errors telling me it can not find the header files from NTTW

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FRTW, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  array_complex.c
1>  fourier.c
1>  ghosts.c
1>  mojette.c
1>  noise.c
1>  radon.c
1>  vector.c
1>u:\ct\newproject\fromsource\frtw\ghosts.c(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nttw/image.h': No such file or directory
1>u:\ct\newproject\fromsource\frtw\radon.c(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nttw/image.h': No such file or directory
1>u:\ct\newproject\fromsource\frtw\vector.h(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nttw/array.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file vector.c)
1>u:\ct\newproject\fromsource\frtw\fourier.h(25): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fftw3.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file fourier.c)
1>u:\ct\newproject\fromsource\frtw\array_complex.h(30): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fftw3.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file array_complex.c)
1>u:\ct\newproject\fromsource\frtw\noise.h(45): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nttw/global.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file noise.c)
1>u:\ct\newproject\fromsource\frtw\mojette.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nttw/prime.h': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm very unsure what to do from here. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your error, I think the debug configuration settings for the FRTW project requires the `Additional Include Directories` setting updating to include the parent directory of the `nttw` directory. If you open the property page for the FRTW project, you can find `Additional Include Directories` under `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `General`.

Don't forget there are different settings for Debug and Release, and you may be changing the Release setting and building under Debug.

You'll probably also need to update the FRTW project to include the static lib file produced by NTTW through `Configuration Properties` -> `Librarian` -> `General` and add the directory the static libraries will be outputted to `Additional Library Directories` and the name of the static libraries to  `Additional Dependencies`. You may need to do something similar to your Playground app project to import the static library that FRTW presumably produces.

Comment: I'm currently testing your suggestions, but I have a stupid question. I noticed that FRTW (probably because I created it as a static library) does not have the "Configuration Properties -> Linker" option. What do I do about that?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer. Instead of `Linker` you should have `Librarian` and that should contain the same setting options to allow you to import the library.

Comment: If this solved the issue for you, can you accept the answer?

Comment: I was changing additional include directories for x64 and running in x86 and wondering why it didn't work.  Adding the additional include directories for all platforms solved the issue.

Comment: @PeterLudvigsen late answer but it can help somebody else : be sure to choose the configuration type (as .exe or .lib) in "Configuration Property > General" and you will be able to see the specific menu.